# Why is adjoining a unit the algebraic counterpart to the one point compactification?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, compactification

There is an interesting relation in which the action of adjoining a unit to an algebra and the one-point compactification come together:

Let $X$ be a non compact but locally compact Hausdorff space and let $C_0(X)$ denote the non-unital algebra of continuous functions on $X$ which vanish at infty (w.r.t. the sup-norm this is a C-*-algebra). We can adjoin a unit element $e$ to $C_0(X)$ which yields the unital C*-Algebra $\widetilde{C_0(X)}$. On the other side, we can compactify $X$ to $X^*$ and consider the C-*-algebra of continuous functions $C(X^*)$:

$$
X \to C_0(X) \to \widetilde{C_0(X)} \\
X \to X^* \to C(X^*)
$$

Interestingly both paths have the same result modulo isomorphic equivalence, i.e.
$$
\widetilde{ C_0(X) } \overset{\text{C*}}{\simeq} C(X^*).
$$

Reading about this in Pedersen's *Analysis Now*, p.129:

> If a Banach algebra $\mathfrak A$ has no unit, we may try to embed it isometrically into a larger unital Banach algebra $\mathfrak B$, in such a way that $\mathfrak A$ becomes an ideal in $\mathfrak B$, so large that every nonzero ideal of $\mathfrak B$ has a nonzero intersection with $\mathfrak A$ (an essential ideal). This process is the **algebraic counterpart** of the com­pactification of a topological space (1.7.2). For the classical Banach algebras there is often a natural way of adjoining a unit; but there is always an abstract procedure - the **counterpart** of the one-point compactification.

Another place in the web where I found a similar statement was in [this](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/banach-algebras-the-gelfand-representation-and-the-commutative-gelfand-naimark-theorem/) post:

> Adjoining a unit **corresponds** to passing to the one-point compactification.

I am wondering if this "phenomenon" can be described in terms of category theory (as e.g. in the case of the Banach-Stone theorem) and if there are further examples of this interplay between the one-point compactification and adjoining a unit.

In particular, I am interested in which sense one should understand the terms **counterpart** or **corresponds** in the two cited sources.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is my proof of the mentioned equivalence.

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $X^* = X \cup \{\infty\}$ its one-point compactification. Furthermore, let $(C_0(X), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ be the C*-Algebra of continuous functions vanishing at infinity and $(C(X^*)), \|.\|_\infty)$ be the C*-algebra of continuous functions on $X^*$. Then,
$$
\widetilde{C_0(X)} \simeq C(X^*),
$$
where $\widetilde{\mathcal A}$ denotes the unification of a non-unital algebra $\mathcal A$.

**Proof**. Consider the mapping
$$
\varphi\colon \widetilde{C_0(X)} \to C(X^*), \quad (f, \alpha) \mapsto \overline f + \alpha := \begin{cases} f(x) + \alpha, \quad & x \in X, \\ \alpha, \quad & x = \infty. \end{cases}
$$
We want to show
$$
\|\varphi(f, \alpha)\|_\infty = \|(f,\alpha)\|_{\widetilde{C_0(X)}}.
$$
For this, we use the following

**Lemma**. For $f \in C(X^*)$, we have
$$
s_1 := \sup_{x \in X} |f| = \sup_{x \in X^*} |f| =: s_2.
$$

**Proof**. Let $x_\alpha$ be a net in $X$ with $\lim_\alpha x_\alpha = \infty$. Then, $f(x_\alpha) \leq s_1$ and thus $f(\infty) \leq s_1$. This gives us $s_2 \leq s_1$. The other inequality is obvious. $\square$

On the one hand, we have
$$
\|\varphi(f,\alpha)\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in X^*} |\;\overline f(x) + \alpha\;|
= \sup_{x \in X} |\;\overline f(x) + \alpha\;|
= \sup_{x \in X} |\;f(x) + \alpha\;|
= \|f + \alpha \|_\infty.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\|(f, \alpha)\|_{\widetilde{C_0(X)}} 
= \sup_{g \in C_0(X), \|g\| \leq 1} \|fg + \alpha g\|_\infty 
\leq \sup_{g \in C_0(X), \|g\|\leq 1} \|g\|_\infty \|f + \alpha\|_\infty
\leq \|f + \alpha\|_\infty = \|\varphi(f, \alpha)\|_\infty .
$$

Now, let $(g_i)_{i \in I}$ be an approximate unit in $C_0(X)$. Then,
$$
\|f g_i + \alpha g_i\|_\infty \to \|f + \alpha\|_\infty
$$
which in turn implies
$$
\|(f, \alpha ) \|_{\widetilde{C_0(X)}} = \|\varphi(f, \alpha)\|_\infty.
$$
This proves the claim. $\square$

Feel free to edit this proof or leave a comment if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}\def\Spec{\textsf{Spec}}\def\c{\textsf{c}}\def\u{\textsf{u}}$

> I am interested in which sense one should understand the terms counterpart or corresponds in the two cited sources.

Here's the meaning of "corresponds": there are functors $\Spec \colon C^*\text{-Alg}^\text{op} \to \text{LCHaus}$ (this is part of the Gel'fand equivalence), $\u \colon C^*\text{-Alg}\to C^*\text{-Alg}_1$ (adding a unit) and $\c\colon \text{LCHaus} \to \text{CHaus}$ (compactification). Then the following square is a commutative[1] diagram of functors
$$
\begin{CD}
C^*\text{-Alg} @> \Spec >> \text{LCHaus}\\
@V\u VV @VV\c V\\
C^*\text{-Alg}_1 @>>\Spec|> \text{CHaus}
\end{CD}
$$
where $\Spec|$ is the functor restricted to unitary $C^*$-algebras.

[1] It is filled by a natural isomorphism $\c \circ \Spec \Rightarrow \Spec| \circ \u$, but the canonicicty of this isomorphism makes it implicit everytime

Comment: PS: Take a look at [this book](https://books.google.it/books/about/K_theory_and_C_algebras.html?id=EVOjQgAACAAJ&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y)!

Comment: Thank you for this categorical viewpoint! Could you elaborate more on the used categories and functors, i.e. explain what the morphisms and objects are in each of the used categories? I have some ideas, but want to make sure I am on the right track.

Comment: [Here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~ambrogio/exercise_C_algebras.pdf) you find everything you need in 9 pages you can easily use as a reference. :-)